# How to open new form as new tab in tab control?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have three forms named, MainForm, Form1 and Form2. In MainForm there is one TabControl. I want to open the forms: Form1 and Form2 as new tab in MainForm. I am using Visual Studio and language VB.Net. Is there any way to open the forms as new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change Form1 and Form2 both to be `UserControls`, you can then load those usercontrols a the contents of the tabs.

To change the Form to a UserControl change the following line:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

to

```
public partial class Form1 : UserControl
```

Best practice is to also rename the Form1 by renaming the file in the Solution Explorer. VS should show you a popup window:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### You are renaming a file. Would you also like to perform a rename in this project of all references to the code element 'Form1'?

### Yes   No

Click `Yes`

Then **Build** your solution, and open your main form with the TabControl in it. Also open the ToolBox window, you should see your new UserControl listed on the top. You can now drag 'n drop your usercontrol onto the TabPage that you want.

Question: do you need to show Form1 and Form2 as actual Forms as well?
If yes, you can create Form1 with a single child: UserControl1 and Form2 with a single child: UserControl2

Hth

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But as I am new to VB.Net, can you kindly describe the process or tell me how can I change the forms to UserControl or the process of displaying the form in new tab.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. Actually **public partial class Form1 : UserControl** was considered as error. The UserControl was marked as error "Declaration Expected" I could not find **public partial class Form1 : Form** insted of this there is **Public Class Form1**

Comment: It's ok. I did the same in vb.net. The process u told woks. But the process u told is manual i.e. drag and drop but I want to add the form in tabpages dynamically. Is there any way??